# Test changes from merging three branches

Tags: git

I cloned a repo from master and I need to pull and merge changes from three other branches. The first pull went fine. But on the second pull, I got a merge conflict and I cannot pull from the last branch unless I fix the conflict and commit. However, I do not want to commit to Master branch or push anything to it. I cannot even create new branch either. I just want to test and see if I pull and merge the three branches, they will work.

I am using `git pull origin branch_name`

Comment: It doesn't strictly bear on the answer, but why are you pulling across branches for each merge?  A single fetch followed by three `git merge` commands would work just as well (and with less time spent interacting with the remote).  In fact I use `pull` almost exclusively for cases where I'm just updating a branch from its own upstream...

Answer (score 0):

Let's start by understanding a bit more of what you're trying to do.

You don't want to affect `master`; but if the merge hadn't conflicted, it would've created a merge commit on `master` (the same as if you resolve the conflicts and commit now).  It's essentially not possible (certainly not worth the trouble of working out a method) to merge in multiple branches without creating a commit.

That's really not a big deal, though, because (1) you could always create a temporary branch (or even use detached head state) if you want, and (2) even if you commit it to master, you can always rewind master without having pushed the merge commits; it would only be if you pushed them that then removing them from branch history would become a hassle.

From where you are, you can either complete the merge, or abort it (in which case you'll end up having to start it over and *then* complete it).  I would just complete it.  If you want to immediately move `master` back where it was, then after completing the merge do

```
git reset --hard HEAD^
```

and then

```
git checkout HEAD@{1}
```

You will now be in detached head state, with your current checkout being a dangling commit containing the merge result.  If you want you can create a temporary branch at this point

```
git chekcout -b <temp_branch_name>
```

where `<temp_branch_name>` is whatever you want to call the branch.

Then complete your additional merges, do your tests.  When your done, you can just go back to master and, if you created a temp branch, you can delete it

```
git checkout master
git branch -D <temp_branch_name>
```

Of course the other alternative is to do all the merges on `master`, run your tests, and then

```
git reset --hard HEAD~3
```

to rewind the 3 merge commits.  (Again, remember this option works on the premise that you don't push `master` - and probably don't pull it either - during the time where the merges exist.)